Mapperly - Is it for For Data Transformation(s)
Our team is using Mapperly for Type Coversions of Data.
That relies on my class finding fields of same name in both classes but of different types. then my conversions are called.
How can we call a conversion for a specific field when the types are the same?
Thanks Mark
